# how to efficiently structure code in js package to stop importing everything

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollupjs

I have a package and at the moment, I export everything in the `main`, `index.js`, in package.json, I do this:

`"main": "dist/index.js",`

and index.js looks like this:

```
export * from './types';
export * from './environment';
export * from './uniqueid';
```

But anybody importing anything like this:

`import { identity } from '@cutting/util';`

they will import everything.

I can imort directly from the `dist` directory but it is ugly:

`import { identity } from "@cutting/util/dist/identity";`

Lodash has the `lodash-es` package as a way round this.

How can I get a nicer import without importing everything?

Comment: ok then why is `import { map } from 'lodash'` so expensive?  and why does `lodash-es` exist?

Comment: webpact can't tell what is dead if it is all `export ° from`.  happy to be wrong but I don't think I am

Comment: https://www.azavea.com/blog/2019/03/07/lessons-on-tree-shaking-lodash/

Comment: import foo from 'lodash/foo'. import { foo } from 'lodash' will not tree-shake, nor will, obviously, import _ from 'lodash'

Comment: "they will import everything." so you verufied that in the generated build? Because actually it should be able to treeshake that.

Comment: using webpack-bundle-analyzer yes I have.

Comment: can you qualify should with evidence

Comment: `import foo from 'lodash/foo'` is good but I don't want all my files in the root.  `import { foo } from 'lodash'` is bad for reasons I stated in the question